# How to return User's username from ForeignKey in __unicode__ return?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return User's username in Debt class unicode method.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    balance = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username // this one works

class Debt(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="who")
    whom = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="whom")
    ammount = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.who.user.username //this one does not work
```

However, `return self.who.user.username` gives `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Julius'` error. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: http://dpaste.com/03ZB5TA

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question instead of linking to external sites. The traceback contains `return str(self.who)` - you're not showing the actual code that is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I changed it after the submition. However, both code samples return the same error. Here is the updated traceback: http://dpaste.com/2SYYNDB#

Comment: Is the `who_id` in the debt table definitely an integer, or is it storing strings like `'Julius'`? Did you create the tables with Django or are you using an existing database? Did  you always have `who = models.ForeignKey()` or have you changed it?

Comment: Yeah.. After flushing the database it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `who_id` column in your database was storing strings like `'Julius'`. This was out of sync with the foreign key in your model - Django expected it to contain integers instead.